# Android: Grabbing Voice

Tags: android

Are there APIs for grabbing the voice (in both directions) during a call? I'm interested in whether it can be intercepted before it's sent out (outgoing) and before it's played by the speaker (incoming).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no API to access the in-call voice audio (inbound or outbound).

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, there is an API for it. Try to look at the classes `AudioRecord` and `MediaRecord`,  and `AudioManager` as well. However these classes are not supported by all firmware. You can also check out [this program](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.record.my.call), I am using it on Samsung galaxy S with success.